# Digitizing rectangles/ovals in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I added the new vector layer in QGIS and I want to draw a circle of 500M or 1000M from center.

I also added the pluginn **Rectangles ovals digitizing in QGIS**. But the options of this pluginn is not active.

How do I use this plugin?

[image: pluginn options are not active under red highlighted box]

Answer (score 6):

If I see well, the geometry type of the layer available in your table of content is "POINT". In order to draw polygons, you first need to create an empty polygon layer (layer > new > new shapefile layer, see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvuvmCOnpoM). You will then be able to use polygon editing tools.

Please also note that if you want a circle around each of your points, you can use the buffer tool (vector > geoprocessing tool > buffer)

Comment: It's somehow obvious, but beside having a polygon layer in the project, that layer must be selected in the layers panel and with edition enabled.

Answer (score 5):

I also had this problem. Re-start QGIS helped (as helped several times before when newly installed plug-ins resisted to get activated).