# How to use QGIS plugin "Rectangles, ovals digitizing tools"

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, polygon-creation

I installed the Rectangles, ovals digitizing tools-plugin, found it on the toolbar, but it's inactive.
I made a layer to which I want to add rectangles, it's visible and editable...
The plugin bar is grey and inactive.

What to do?

Comment: Be wary... That plugin has known issues and will cause your QGIS to get slower and slower over time.

Comment: Thnx. Any alternatives (preferably with the possibility to set dimensions of the polygons)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Digitizing rectangles/ovals in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82130/digitizing-rectangles-ovals-in-qgis)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **Rectangles Ovals Digitizing** plugin only works for **polygon** layers, not for point or line layers.

[image: Polygon example]

Comment: Is there a way to change or set dimensions to rectangles?

Comment: @Rob - Not that I'm aware of, I don't see an option to change the dimensions. I have only used this tool a handul of times so perhaps another who is more experienced in it could advise.