# Add shape graphics in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I want to draw a simple graphics rectangle\ circule in QGIS 2.12, just as i do it in ArcGIS:

[image]

[image]

I red

1. [Digitizing rectangles/ovals in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82130/how-to-use-rectangles-ovals-digitizing-in-qgis)
2. [Drawing tools to add circles, arrows, lines for QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94728/drawing-tools-to-add-circles-arrows-lines-for-qgis)

and installed the tool "Rectangles ovals digitizing in QGIS", but it works only when i edit a layer. I want graphics rectangle box and not editing a layer, just has in the Print Composer Layout

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Creating a rectangle is surely an edit function.

So you have to create a new layer of type polygon, give it a filename, and turn it into edit mode. Then you can draw the rectangle.

If you just want decoration for your print output, you can have rectangles and circles in the print composer.

Comment: The rectangle in the question's picture is a graphic, and not a feature.  In ArcMap, features have full editing capabilities, whereas graphics are drawn using tools from the Draw toolbar, and there are relatively few editing capabilities that can be used on them.